# Fix on scroll but with varying screen size no set pixel distance

Tags: javascript, scroll, fixed

I have a div with an image background thats height is 100% so it fills the screen on any device. At the bottom of the screen is then a navigation bar. When the page is scrolled I want the navigation bar to fix to the top of the screen at a set distance away from the top.
I have tried using this JavaScript:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 587) {
      $('.hnav').addClass('hfixed');
  } else {
      $('.hnav').removeClass('hfixed');
  }});
```

It works fine on my screen but on any other screen it doesn't because the navigation changes distance from the top depending on the window size because of the 100% height image.

How can I get the navigation to fix in place when its a set distance from the top regardless of the window size??

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a code example to test please? A working web page

Comment: the web page it is on is obuhc.com its the white bar at the bottom I want to fix bellow the dark nav at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the element's position with element.getBoundingClientRect(), so you can add the 'hfixed' class once this returns a top value of 0:

```
var nav = $('.hnav');
var pos = nav.position();                      
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windowpos + 50 >= pos.top) {
        nav.addClass("hfixed");
    } else {
        nav.removeClass("hfixed");  
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

Added an extra margin of 50px to the calc, because the top bar.

**EDIT 2:**

Changed the example, now it's based on [this](http://www.pixelbind.com/examples/stick-a-div/)

**EDIT 3:**

Add the 50px margin because the top bar to the new example

Comment: I just tired this but it makes it flicker while scrolling I would prefer it to be smooth. I found this http://www.pixelbind.com/examples/stick-a-div/ but not sure how to implement it into my site

Comment: It's working now but when I then scroll back up it's staying fixed to top not removing the class

Comment: Oh, that's because the getBoundingClientRect, didn't tought that, let me edit it :)

Comment: Wait, having an issue

Comment: Something is going wrong, go over to obuhc.com and have a look. Its jumping from half way to the top on larger screens

Comment: The code is minified, can't read it properly, can you upload it without minifying?

Comment: Ah don't worry I found the problem, when the window is resized it happens, you have to reload the page for it to work. But it would work fine when any user loads it in their browser

Comment: Yes I'll do that now so you can look, see if this can be fixed